# same websocket code does not work on other computer

Tags: python, websocket, binance

I have 2 computers and I copied a program from one to another and it did not work. It is an auto trading program that uses websockets to get kline data from binance. debugging the code i found that it stops on the line below

```
response = await socket.recv()
```

i checked the code, used spot instead of futures(worked but didnt on futures), ran it on my first computer(both futures and spot worked), reinstalled ubuntu. how can i fix it?

heres the code

```
import asyncio
import websockets as ws

async def main():
    print('Start')
    #async with ws.connect('wss://stream.binance.com:9443/stream?streams=btcusdt@kline_1m') as socket:
    async with ws.connect('wss://fstream.binance.com/stream?streams=btcusdt@kline_1m') as socket:
        response = await socket.recv()
        print(response)
                

if(__name__ == '__main__'):
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

one with wss://stream(spot) works and wss://fstream(futures) does not

Comment: Please include your error messages, for best results.

Comment: error does not occur it pauses on the line and does not go on

Comment: Sounds like it’s stuck waiting for a response that never comes - I’d compare firewall configs on the 2 machines, and check fw logs for anything blocked on the non-working machine.

Comment: if firewall was the problem then it spot should've not worked

Comment: Your initial statement is that it's not working... if the firewall blocks the outbound connection, then I'd expect the **creation of the connection to fail**. If it's only blocking the response, I'd expect you'd be **stuck in limbo with an open connection**; this is the failure mode you're describing in your comment.